# How large should n be chosen in to have: $|e^x - p_n(x)| < 10^{-15}$?

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

How large should n be chosen in:

[image]

to have: $\lvert e^x - p_n(x) \rvert \leq 10^{-15} $,  $-1  \leq x  \leq 1 $

How can i solve it?

A lot of value are missing

Comment: $p_n$ is the Taylor/Maclaurin polynomial or *some* polynomial?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla it is taylor polynomial

Comment: Use some remainder formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder.

Comment: I try but how can i solve with no value of x0 and x ?

Comment: It appears be that $x_0 = 0$ and you must find a bound for the reminder valid $\forall x\in[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\forall x\in[-1,1]:\ \left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}e^c\right|\le\frac{e}{(n+1)!}.$$
(Why?)

Comment: I did exactly the same, thank you a lot